# Python queue stop when max reached

Tags: python, queue

In the code below, I'm putting number on a queue from a thread and retrieving and printing them from the main thread. It's supposed to print number from 0 to 99 but it's stops at 9. The max size of the queue is 10.

```
def fetch(queue):
    for i in range(100):
        queue.put(i)

def main():
    queue = Queue(maxsize=10)
    Thread(target=fetch, args=(queue,)).start()

    while not queue.empty():
        item = queue.get()
        print(item)
```

When I run this code I get:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The program doesn't stop, terminating it with `ctl+c` results:

```
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1560, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: The queue probably runs empty for a short period of time which exits the while-loop and the main thread. But the fetch thread is and remains active yet and waits to put the next number in the queue (which never happens). Due to the active non-daemon thread the program stays active.

Comment: Solution: The fetch thread puts a special marker (e. g. None) in the queue finally at the end and main thread only terminates when getting the marker.

Comment: Thank you, I never thought of marking the end.

Answer (score 1):

The `queue.empty()` method is notoriously unreliable due to the nature of threading. You should use a sentinal value to mark the end of the queue:

```py
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep

def fetch(queue):
    sleep(1)
    for i in range(100):
        queue.put(i)
    queue.put(None)     # None is a sentinal value

def sink1(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if item == None:
            break
        print(item)

def main():
    queue = Queue(maxsize=10)
    t=Thread(target=fetch, args=(queue,))
    t.start()
    sink1(queue)

main()
print('Done')
```

I tried your code and it seemed to work for me. I then added `sleep(1)` to the `fetch()` function and then the program just quits immediately since the main thread immediately sees an empty queue.